# Without scheduling how to trigger BODS Jobs from Azure

Tags: sap-data-services

We have a requirement to trigger SAP BODS jobs from Azure with parameters. Can this be achieved through Azure Functions or Logic APP. Is there any other alternatives? Can you please provide some details along with examples preferably in Python. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.